# I need to automate a process to open files created by another application

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a JAVA application on a server that creates log files.
I have, in other server, an application (VB.NET) that process those logs to search some strings; if I manually select the file it works all OK.

Now I need that the second application automatically open every new log file on the remote server every one minute.

So I wonder if there's any way to know when a new log file is created or what are the new files created since last minute.

The files have the following format name **server.log.*.log** so the files with different format name must be ignored.

**More info:**
There's a second JAVA application on the first sever that delete logs older than one day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) every minutes to get the list of all the files in the folder. Compare it to the previous list (that you keep in memory) and process the new files.

An other option is to monitor the folder for any changes. This can be done using the [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class. By setting the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path(v=vs.110).aspx) and the proper [NotifyFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see which files were created with the [Created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx) event as soon (or almost) as they appear.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think the first solution too, but the problem that I found is that the list of files in RAM must have a limit, if I add new file names constantly inevitably the RAM will be overflowed.

Comment: I add more info on the first post.

Comment: @E_Blue [size of file name, ~15] * [number of files] = [memory in ram] I don't think this will be very high. If there's a pattern, let say the date is written in the filename, then you could exclude some old files. Also, when using Getfiles, you can get the last modified date of each files. You could exclude all old dates.